# How can I compute the temperature change from the de-excitation of excited particle species?

Tags: thermodynamics

The motivation for the question in the title is that I have some formula given,

$$\Delta T=\frac{3410\ \gamma_{O_2}}{2.5+\gamma_{O_2}},$$

where $\gamma_{O_2}$ is the molar fraction of oxygen in a binary micture and the ratio of oxygen and rate gas heat capacities are supposed to be 7.5, if that helps. And there is another one with a factor $\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}$ multiplied, where $\eta$ is a singlet delta oxigen efficiency.

Where does this formula come from?

Comment: Could you provide the reference for that formula given. Is it from a journal article or a textbook? If you could provide a little more context and some evidence of what you have been able to come up with on your own, it would help folks generate a better answer.

Comment: @BenNorris: [equation (9)](http://iopscience.iop.org/0022-3727/40/2/R01/) and the one before that.